# iOS invalid binary for something I didn't use

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have provided Apple's message below. I don't know how I could have tried to access the users calendar or bluetooth peripheral. Are there any settings somewhere in the project that could cause this? I have included the libraries I have used too. Also does the code that apple wants me to add prompt the user to allow my app access to their calendar? Because I don't need it.

" This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team "

[image: Libraries]

[image: Capablities]

Comment: Library (.a) which you are using might be using bluetooth & calendar internally

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you are using library of `AppLovinSDK`, there is a chance that this library is accessing calendar & bluetooth due to which you need to do the below entries in your apps `info.plist` file

You need to add NSCalendarsUsageDescription value in your app's info.plist file.

[image: Like this]

Add a message why your app is using calendar

Along with that add NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription value as well.

[image: Like this]

Add your message why your app is using bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention in plist in key description, why u want to access these permission or for what your application does with these permissions.

It should be clear to User, why app needs your private information.

For more info [check this link](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/requesting-permission/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the use permission before access the user private data like contact number, photos , location , calendar , etc. in iOS 10 Apple is extending the scope of privacy control. You have to declare in Info.plist file access of any private data.

Just you need to add the Calendar privacy in info.plist

**Calendar :**

**Key :** Privacy - Calendars Usage Description

**Value :** $(PRODUCT_NAME) calendar events

This will show an alert. 
[image]

**For more details:**
The complete iOS 10 privacy details:

**Calendar :**
Key      :  Privacy - Calendars Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) calendar events

**Reminder :**
Key      :   Privacy - Reminders Usage Description
Value  :   $(PRODUCT_NAME) reminder use

**Contact :**
Key       :   Privacy - Contacts Usage Description
Value    :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) contact use

**Photo :**
Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use

**Bluetooth Sharing :**
Key       :  Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) Bluetooth Peripheral use

**Microphone :**
Key        :  Privacy - Microphone Usage Description
Value    :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) microphone use

**Camera :**
Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use

**Location :**
Key      :  Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) location use

Key       :  Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) location use

**Heath :**
Key      :  Privacy - Health Share Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) heath share use

Key      :  Privacy - Health Update Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) heath update use

**HomeKit :**
Key      :  Privacy - HomeKit Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) home kit use

**Media Library :**
Key      :  Privacy - Media Library Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) media library use

**Motion :**
Key      :  Privacy - Motion Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) motion use

**Speech Recognition :**
Key      :  Privacy - Speech Recognition Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) speech use

**SiriKit  :** 
Key      :  Privacy - Siri Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) siri use

**TV Provider :** 
Key      :  Privacy - TV Provider Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) tvProvider use

Answer (score 0):

I simply updated my AdMob SDK to the latest version (7.1.6). It seems it was the issue.